# Scala: How to cast this if-then-else ladder as pattern matching

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have the following code which works using a if-then-else ladder:

```
val test: Array[Array[Int]] = ...
val dim = 3 
if (dim < test.length - 1) {
    1   
} else {
    0
}
```

casting it as pattern matching I attempt:

```
val dim = 3 
val maxDim = test.length - 1
dim match {
   case _ < maxDim => {
       1        
   }
   case _ => {
       0        
   }
}
```

but this produces multiple errors ... how can I do it as a pattern matching?

UPDATE: another attempt would be

```
dim match {
    case maxDim => 0
    case _ => 1
}
```

but doesn't work either

Comment: There's a hint in the phrase "pattern matching". It's not just providing alternative keywords for if/else, which is how you seem to be trying to usie it. @Mastran has provided the answer, but, really, any introductory text on Scala would have covered this. So, in each case, provide a pattern to match (which can be a numeric literal as in your example), provide a guard to further test that match, then specify what should happen when pattern matches and guard condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an if-clause in your match-case if you need to test a boolean expression. Try this:

```
dim match {
  case i if i < maxDim => 1
  case _ => 0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`test.lift(dim).fold(0){ _ => 1}`

This is not pattern matching, but the whole point is that you don't need pattern matching in this case.

**Explanation**: your `if-then` thingy is basically testing whether the index is valid for an array, and returns 1 if it is, and 0 if it isn't (I am assuming, the lack of test for negative values was an oversight, and not an intentional feature).

Collections in scala are `PartialFunctions` from `Int` to the element type, that are defined on the domain of indexes valid for the collection and return the value of the element at that index.

`PartialFunction.lift` is  utility that lets you test whether a partial function is defined and apply it if it is in one go. If it is defined at the argument value, it will return the `Option` of the result, otherwise, you will get `None`.

So, `test.lift(dim)` above returns `None` if `dim` was invalid, and `Some` array otherwise. We then `.fold` the option: `.fold` returns first parameter is the option is empty, and executes the function if it is not.

Putting it all together: we get an `Option` indicating whether the index was valid, then `.fold` it to return 0 if it was empty or 1 if not.